# Unique Constraint format for non-directed graph - given (1,2), prevent (2,1)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a non-directed graph table in my SQL Server (2008) database and I want a constraint to prevent duplicates.
My link table has 2 columns, (City1, City2), both integer references into the Cities table.  I can use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CityConnections
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CityConnections_OneWayOnly UNIQUE (City1, City2)
```

Which does half of what I want but this does not prevent adding a "reverse" connection.

Google showed me

```
... UNIQUE (MIN(City1,City2), MAX(City1,City2))
```

Which looks like it will do exactly what I want but the syntax is invalid .

I have also tried a complicated constraint using CASE but I couldn't get this syntax correct either.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you can control your entry to the table, the following should work;

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CityConnections
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CityConnections_Unq UNIQUE (City1, City2)
ALTER TABLE dbo.CityConnections
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CityConnections_OneWayOnly CHECK (City1 < City2)
```

Comment: +1. That's what I'd usually recommend. Optionally, a trigger can be added so that insertion and update can work in either order.

Comment: Just for completeness, my trigger looks like this:

`CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_CityConnection_Insert  
   ON  [CityConnections]  
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 INSERT [CityConnections]
 SELECT (CASE WHEN [City1] < [City2] THEN [City1] ELSE [City2] END) as City1, (CASE WHEN [City1] > [City2] THEN [City1] ELSE [City2] END) as City2
 FROM inserted;
END`

Answer (score 0):

Great, as soon as I ask a question that's been puzzling me for ages, I get inspiration and figure it out myself.
My solution was to add computed columns and use those as the unique constraint (index)

I now have:

```
CREATE TABLE [CityConnections]
(
    [City1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [City2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [minCity]  AS (case when [City1]<[City2] then [City1] else [City2] end),
    [maxCity]  AS (case when [City1]>[City2] then [City1] else [City2] end),
CONSTRAINT [CK_CityConnections_OneWayOnly] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [minCity] ASC,
    [maxCity] ASC
)
```

Edit - After further thought (and comments) I agree that this is not the best solution

Comment: The index created to support `CK_CityConnections_OneWayOnly` is completely wasted here unless your queries reference `minCity,maxCity` and if they do why store `City1,City2` at all? MarkD's answer seems more efficient.

Comment: "The answer below" is a bad way to reference answers on here - answers change position based on votes. If you wish to refer to someone else's answer, it usually best to *link* to the answer (there's a share link below each answer from which you can copy an appropriate link address)

Comment: Actually, on further consideration I agree
The computed columns are a mess (I would have preferred to compute them in the constraint)
Also, as you pointed out, the constraint actually becomes an Index which is in-efficient